# Java Signed Right Shift

Tags: java

I have seen this in a java code.

```
int n = 300 //passed through a function
size = (n + 31) >> 5 //size = 10
```

what could be the significance of `5`?
What is the significance of `31` //should something to do with int size (31 bit + 1 sign)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The significance of 5 is that 32 = 2^5.

```
size = (n + 31) >> 5
```

sets `size` to `ceiling(n/32)`, which is the number of 32-bit integers needed to store `n` bit flags.

The addition of 31 to `n` is to make sure that the dividend is at least as large as the smallest multiple of 32 greater than or equal to `n`.

Comment: @TheZ That has not much to do with it. For easier understanding rewrite it as: `(n + 31) / 32` which means "get ceiling of n / 32" - that works fine for every number, i.e. `(n + x - 1) / x` would be the general solution. Shifting instead of division is also mixed in here, but is a separate topic and I think known by most people here already.

Comment: I'm assuming this can't be more efficient than (n + 31) / 32 ?

Comment: @CoryKendall It can, if the compiler is daft. But since it's usually a one-time computation to find the size of the array needed, there's no real reason to do it, except being too used to bit-twiddling.

Comment: @Cory It's not equivalent if `n < 0` so the compiler can't in all cases avoid the division, so it can help a bit if you know that `n > 0` (and the compiler doesn't) or you actually want the different interpretation for negative numbers. (Note that the compiler can still trick a bit and avoid the division even if n could be negative with a bit more work).